# Erro ao adicionar o pacote Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Desig no projeto de apis

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework-core, migrations, dotnet-cli

Fala pessoal

Criei uma minimal api usando donet (7.0.402) e estou tentando criar as Migrations para o banco de dados.
A execução do comando **dotnet ef migrations**, criticou a falta a falta de referência ao pacote Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design no projeto de api.

Mas ao executar o comando para adicionar o pacote, no projeto de apis, recebo a mensagem: **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design' é incompatível com as estruturas 'all' no projeto**

Alguém teria alguma pista do quê poderia ser?

Comment: compartilha com a gente como esta o csproj dos seus projetos.

Answer (score -1):

Para os que passarem pelo mesmo problema, o erro acontecia por incompatibilidade de versão entre do sdk que eu estava trabalhando (7.0.402) e a última versão do pacote microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design disponível (8.0.0).

após instalar uma versão do pacote compatível com o framework que eu estava trabalhando (7.0.14), o erro deixou de acontecer.

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design --version 7.0.14

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).